# What does "associate" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

This is a definition for "tune in" from Merriam-Webster:

"to **associate** oneself with what is happening or one's surroundings"

**associate**

1. To connect in the mind or imagination: *"I always somehow associate Chatterton with autumn"* (John Keats).(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

Is this the correct definition? The reason I'm asking is because there's this phrase **"turn on, tune in, drop out"** which was popularized by Timothy Leary in the '60s or '70s but when I searched different dictionaries for **"tune in"** there are no definitions like the one from Merriam-Webster at the beginning of this post. The only definitions I found for it were...

**"tune in"**

2. To pay attention to, become aware of, or be responsive (to someone or something).
   *My father never tuned in when we were growing up. Our mother essentially raised*(Farlex Dictionary of Idioms)

...and although the definition from Merriam-Webster seems correct to me on account of the fact that Timoty Leary's phrase was used by the **hippies** and he was sort of a **guru** like Ram Dass or Sri Ramana Maharshi who were always talking about the **universe** and us **being the part of it** Therefore the way I interpret the phrase "turn on, tune in, drop out" with the definition from Merriam-Webster would be something like

- turn-on-probably means to start doing drugs
- tune in- "to associate(meaning connect) oneself with what is
  happening or one's surroundings" **or realize that you are the one with the surrounding environment or universe**
- drop out-To abandon society and conventional values.

Comment: This is a question for the editors of Merriam-Webster.

Comment: Of course, it's right.  Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: **Associate oneself** does not mean the same as **associate [something] with [something else].**

Comment: @Kate Bunting What does "Associate oneself " mean Kate?

Comment: Well, it can mean 'join' or 'link yourself with' a person or group of people - but in the context of M-W's definition it means 'feel linked to', 'interact with' (as in Leary's own explanation which I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: @KateBunting Would "feel connected" also work? Can I rephrase the M-W's definition to: "to feel connected with what is happening or one's surroundings"

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia page for "Turn on, tune in, drop out", Leary himself said that *"Tune in" meant 'interact harmoniously with the world around you'.*

Comment: The man was a giant equine rear-end but this is probably is best legacy.